# pipeline delimiter and some fields having comma those should be placed in double quotes and it supposed to be taken as single filed

Tags: awk, csv

i Have one csv file.

input.

```
India|Andhra|asd,ged,ijn|telangana|41657|hgjd,dfef,edf|dfd
```

output

```
India,Andhra,"asd,ged,ijn",telangana,41657,"hgjd,dfef,edf",dfd
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? How did that attempt deviate from your expectations?

Comment: There are plenty of characters available in the body of your Question to describe the question. Do not feel like you need to fit it all into the title, please & thank you!

Comment: awk '{gsub(/[^|]+/,"\"&\"")}1' i tried this but it is replacing whole data

Comment: awk '{gsub(/[^|]+/,"\"&\"")}1' i tried this but it is replacing whole data
Input:
India|Andhra|asd,ged,ijn|telangana|41657|hgjd,dfef,edf|dfd
apple|grape|orange|strawberry|12543|mango
output:
India,Andhra,"asd,ged,ijn",telangana,41657,"hgjd,dfef,edf",dfd
apple,grape,orange,strawberry,12543,mango
or
India|Andhra|"asd,ged,ijn"|telangana|41657|"hgjd,dfef,edf|dfd"
apple|grape|orange|strawberry|12543|mango

Comment: `awk -F\| -vOFS=, '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i~OFS)$i="\""$i"\""; print}'`; but as the other have said, use a csv tool, that knows how to deal with csv's format pitfalls.

Comment: PLEASE. Put your exta information into your question. **Make it easy for us to help you**.

Answer (score 2):

Using `csvformat` from [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io):

```
$ csvformat -d '|' file.csv
India,Andhra,"asd,ged,ijn",telangana,41657,"hgjd,dfef,edf",dfd
```

The tools in the csvkit toolbox are CSV-aware (they are all CSV parsers for modifying and querying and generally working with CSV files on the command line).

Here, I use `csvformat` to reformat the input file and I specify that the field delimiter in the input is a pipe symbol by using `-d '|'`. The output will by default use commas as field delimiters, and the tool will escape and quote things as necessary.

Comment: awk '{gsub(/[^|]+/,"\"&\"")}1'    I tried this but it is replacing whole data.         I tried with csvformat -d '|' file.csv I'm getting error as -ksh: csvformat: not found [No such file or directory]

Comment: @Aswani `csvformat` is seldom installed by default. You would have to install csvkit manually.  This could be done with `pip install --user csvkit` and then adding `~/.local/bin` to your path.

Comment: its a shared server so we dont have rights to install

Comment: @Aswani The command I mentioned would install in your home directory.

Comment: when I'm trying to install its prompting error as -ksh: pip: not found [No such file or directory]

Comment: @Aswani That means that you don't have `pip` installed either. In that case, I would wait until someone gives you an answer that you _can_ use.

Answer (score 0):

If you have ruby installed:

```
ruby -rcsv -e '
    rdr = CSV.new(File.new(ARGV.shift), col_sep: "|")
    wtr = CSV.new($stdout)
    rdr.each {|row| wtr << row}
' file.csv
```

```
India,Andhra,"asd,ged,ijn",telangana,41657,"hgjd,dfef,edf",dfd
```

Comment: No ruby installed in my server:(

Comment: I'm using putty and im writing  unix shell script for file formatting